# SSL GRPC Service running inside docker

Tags: ssl, docker, kubernetes, grpc

I have multiple docker containers running various GRPC servers. Currently I start these servers like this:

```
   server.bind('0.0.0.0:50051',grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure());
```

Obviously this created a grpc server that is not user ssl.

For my public facing API gateway I am using lets encrypt to generate SSL certificates. Is there a way I can do the same for my downstream containers?

Note: I am using kubernetes so my certificates are automatically provisioned and managed by Kube-Lego

Comment: Regardless of how the SSL certificates are provisioned (e.g. from KubeLego in your case), you basically need to create an instance of ServerCredentials that are using the certificates provided by your environment (they will likely come as files). Also see https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/bb41e0a29049ccde6b245281dc71d02b1fda1695/netty/src/main/java/io/grpc/netty/GrpcSslContexts.java#L113